# Why does getGeneratedKeys() not return any results following an INSERT?

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have a table which has one column which is defined as auto-generate-key. When the following code is executed, I expect a new key to be generated but this is not the case. One row is inserted but the ResultSet for `ps.getGeneratedKeys()` is empty.

I am using DB2: SQLLIB_ADCL_V97FP1.

```
        conn = getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        String query = 
            "INSERT INTO MyTable " +
            "  (messe_nr, land5, variable_nr, bezeichnung_en, bezeichnung_de) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setInt(1, fair.getFairId());
        ps.setString(2, variable.getCountryCode());
        ps.setInt(3, variable.getSort());
        ps.setString(4, variable.getLabel_en());
        ps.setString(5, variable.getLabel_de());

        log.debug(query);
        int count = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(count == 1) {
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next()) {
                variable.setId(rs.getBigDecimal(1).intValue());
            } else {
                log.error("Could not get autogen key after variable insert");
                throw new AVMSException(1500);
            }
            rs.close();
        }
        log.debug("inserted " + count);

        ps.close();
        conn.commit();
```

**UPDATE**

I have just deployed the project to the test server and the problem does not occur. Something is broken on my development system - but what? I did install a Java update a day or two back - 1.7.0_13 - could that cause such a problem :-/ ?

Comment: Can you share `CREATE` statement for `MyTable`

Comment: @Bulat - I don't have direct access to the **CREATE**. I checked with the admins who confirm that `VARIABLE_ID` is an auto generated key.

Comment: Can you check that value is actually being generated. Also I think you can pass name of the field to getGeneratedKeys() and check what happens in that case.

Comment: @Bulat - The row is inserted. The version of JDBC I have does not expect any parameters for `getGeneratedKeys()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try, it is working for me:

```
prepStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, new String[]{"YOUR_ID_FIELD"});

//Setting Bind-Variables

prepStmt.executeUpdate();

        rs = prepStmt.getGeneratedKeys();  
        while (rs.next())
        {
            tAdresse.getAdressid().setValue(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("Key: " + tAdresse.getAdressid().getIntValue());
        }
```

Comment: thanks! Wish I'd noticed your post earlier. Just found the same solution and it does work for me too.

Answer (score 7):

You should pass "Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS" as the second parameter of your PreparedStatement.
The code looks like this:-

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name?user=databse_username&password=database_password");

PrepardStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO author(authorName) values(?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ps.setString(1, "Mark Twain");

int i = ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println(i + " Records Added.");

ResultSet gK = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
if(gK.next()) {
long generatedId = gK.getLong(1);
} else {
System.out.println("Message => Generated Key cannot be accessed.");
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here "author" is the table name and "authorName" is the column name.